# Can’t locate Local Publications folder under Replication folder in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can't locate Local Publications folder under Replication folder in SQL Server 2005. Replication components are installed. I am using SQL Server 2005 not express edition.

I just installed SQL Server 2005 with replication compoenents and right click on Replication folder, there I can see just 3 options. 1) Update Replication Password. 2) New -> Subscription. 3)Refresh

*I have also posted this question on serverfault but no response from last more than one hour so I am trying it here.*

**EDIT:**
Express edition is also installed on this machine but I am unable to find complete options under replication in SQL Server 2005 standard edition.

Thanks.

Comment: which version of SQL are you using ?

Comment: SQL server 2005 standard edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is sql server 2005 standard edition but Management studio was **Express**. That is why I was unable to see all options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your server to be a publisher when you configured replication ? Maybe the replication setting configured used this server as a subscriber only.

Comment: I just installed SQL Server 2005 with replication compoenents and right click on Replication folder, there I can see just 3 options. 1) Update Replication Password. 2) New -> Subscription. 3)Refresh

Comment: So, you must use Microsoft SQL Standard, Enterprise or Small Business Server (SBS) editions to publish transaction replication.