# Setting up Publication on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008r2-express

I cannot find the Local Publication folder in the node Replication in my SQL Server Management Studio.

I recently installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition.

I also created two instances for testing purposes.

Solution for SQL Server 2005 is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160093/cant-locate-local-publications-folder-under-replication-folder-in-sql-server-20) but not for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Comment: does 2008 express support replication ? I remember for sql 2005 express we had to install via a separate installer - and then we used to setup problematically (SMO) .

Comment: We can subscribe to any server so publications also should be available

Comment: yes 2008 express can be subscriber , but can not be publisher ! see link i posted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Replication Considerations (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms165686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), a SQL Server Express Edition instance cannot be used as a Publisher or Distributor:

> SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.

However, a SQL Server Express Edition instance can serve as a Subscriber.

You will need a SQL Server Standard Edition instance or higher to configure a publication.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing comments at one place - so it helps others,

SQL 2008 Express can not be used as publisher but can be used as subscriber.

read on MSDN to find out more [Replication Considerations (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms165686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you suggest how to publish in sql 2008 then? Also can u confirm the link is working?

Comment: yes the i am able to read the link , try this alternate , published pdf of same , https://pdfzen.com/516214 . this should help

Comment: for sql 2008 setup - i recommend you to post a separate question - and not in this question - this way it would be clean stack over flow environment ( i am sure you will find many articles on setting up via sql 2008 server ) .

Comment: @RAJ hope you read link / pdf and now clear that can not create publication on sql express - if the answer is yes - please take the responsibility of marking it as answer so that it helps others. ping back if this didn't help

Comment: Thanks for the pdf I am investigating on it. and trying to set up using RMO.

Comment: this is old post but curios to know what happened ? how it was solved ?